# I am getting this error The DNS operation timed out after 20.000144004821777 seconds when running my app in cygwin instead of my windows terminal

Tags: python, cygwin, mongodb-atlas, python-rq

so I am trying to do some background job to run in my flask app , and in order to run the worker, I needed to use cygwin instead of my windows terminal. My application use MongoDb Atlas for documents storage and it works perfectly fine when I "flask run" it from my cmd . But I got the error once I run it or run the worker from cygwin. It is to note that I whitelisted my IP adress and installed the dnspython package , and still got the error. 
Any suggestions about what could be the problem? I don't seem to find any answer in previous asked questions . Thank you.

Comment: not a programming questions so better to use SuperUser. You are not giving us nothing to help you anyway. What python ? Are you mixing cygwin python with settings for not Cygwin one ? Why do you need to run the application under Cygwin ?

Comment: I am using python 3.7 ,  and  Cygwin Terminal is used because 'RQ' package does not run on the Windows native Python interpreter .It can only be run  under Unix emulation layer .

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your dynamic DNS configuration from your ISP. make it static or you can use googleDNS server which is 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4 as your DNS servers.

Comment: Man you just saved me. By the why would dynamic DNS config stop MongoDB Atlas to get connected?

Comment: I was wondering if you could expand on this?  I'm having the same issue, but I can't figure out why its happening.  I can connect to my DB Compass without issue.   PyCharm can connect to my DB.  but I get the same error above when I try to use pymongo via python script

Comment: @keynesiancross were you able to resolve this? Pulling my hair out trying to troubleshoot. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I hit and resolved this same issue hit today w/ cygwin, python3.8, dnspython 1.16.0 by updating to dnspython 2.0.0 and ensuring there was a valid /etc/resolv.conf in place.